# what is range checking in c?

Tags: c, range-checking

While I'm reading some C tutorials, I found this line which I do not understand:

> C Lacks range-checking

What does that mean?

Another small question: how can I pause code to not terminate quickly after finishing? I think we say `System("PAUSE")` or some thing like that. How can I make it in C?

Comment: One question per question please. C tutorials are silly; get a book. The author is probably talking about how array bounds are not validated for you on access. Why is this tagged C++? Don't implement pause-at-end in your program; it's the environment's fault if it vanishes after execution, so fix the environment.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal one comment per comment please ;)

Comment: googling for your highlighted phrase immediatly gives me this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you can define operations whose logical result is outside of the range of values allowed for the type. e.g.

```
unsigned char a = 0xFF;
unsigned char b = a + 1;
```

The compiler will very happily allow this, and return a result of `0x00`.  `0xFF + 1` overflows the one byte storage of ***a***.  Notice that 0x00 is just the low-order 8 bits of the correct answer '0x100`.  This can be repaired with:

```
unsigned char a = 0xFF;
unsigned b = (unsigned)a + 1;
```

which first makes more room for the value in a by converting it to a larger integer type and saving it to a larger type.

A similar issue is *bounds checking* in which the compiler will happily let you write:

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
i = 1000;
b = a[i];
```

(EDITED based on the comments:)
After executing this code, an exception will likely be thrown, but the compiler doesn't care at all.

Comment: Or just `unsigned b = a + 1`, since the wrap-around in the first example occurs (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`) when the value `0x100` is stored to `b`, not when `1` is added to `0xFF`.

Comment: As WTP said on your deleted answer, `b` is not guaranteed to be some arbitrary value 995 words off the end of the array. The behavior of the code is undefined. It could crash, catch fire, raise a hardware exception for stack overflow, etc, instead of setting `b` to any value.

Comment: @SteveJessop This is c, not c++ where someone could overload `operator[]`.  In c, `a[i]` is only syntatic sugar on `*(a + i)`.

Comment: yes, and `a+1000` is not a valid pointer value. Dereferencing an invalid pointer value has undefined behavior. Suppose there's a guard page at the top of the stack, and you hit that, you'll get a segfault or whatever, not some arbitrary value in `b`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Sorry to continue to disagree, but a+1000 IS a valid pointer value in C.  See for example http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html.  You get whatever is at that location, interpreted as an integer.  You can interpret ANY data of the right size as an integer.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment was careless. `a+1000` is not a valid pointer arithmetic operation. Even performing it has undefined behavior, whether you dereference the result or not. It's just that with modern architectures, you're very unlikely to notice anything amiss if you don't dereference it.

Comment: Specifically, look at 6.5.6/8 in C99. "If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned."

Comment: And FWIW you cannot in general interpret just any data as an integer for two reasons: (1) trap representations, (2) strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @SteveJessop Back in the K&R days memory was just a sequence of bytes that anyone could read or write to for good or ill.  But you're right, modern architectures weaken my statement because of memory protection architectures.  So we have some agreement at last.  So I'll adjust my statement.

Comment: BTW, I haven't coded proper C since around 1997, so I guess I should be more careful to take C99 into account!  I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can often say system("pause") to make the environment wait for you to press enter, provided that you have #included *stdlib.h*. However, you should be aware of the following:

- It is not considered anywhere near good practice to rely on the presence of a pause.exe command in the current environment. It may be true on most Windows systems, but is generally not true on Unices or Macs. So you would be limiting your otherwise portable program to a single platfom.
- You may want to consider why you want the user to press enter. Most people think it's good if programs do their work and then just exit. It's very uncommon for "real" programs to wait for user confirmation in this manner. If you just want to see what the DOS prompt says before it closes itself, perhaps thie problem lies with the DOS prompt rather than with your program?

I remember asking this same question when I started out with programming, but I have since realised that pausing programs is the Wrong Thing in most cases.

Comment: I've always wondered why people use `system("pause");`? Is there something wrong with `getchar()`? Is non-portability desirable or something?

Comment: @Dave There may be text left in the input buffer, in which case getchar() does nothing. I remember that in C++, the cin>> way of getting input would leave newlines in the buffer, making that technique fail.

Comment: Then, `while(getchar()!=EOF);` should do it. This is mostly so IDE-folk can see the output of their programs, and pressing `ctrl-d` isn't hard.